# Can i fetch list data in 2010 Sharepoint Designer Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I want to pull list items in Workflow but i am using sharepoint Designer 2010. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No You cannot do that in 2010 workflows.

But you can do that in SharePoint 2013 workflows. That is storing the list items in a dictionary and then iterating through them one by one.